# Java 8 Sort HashMap where map key is an object of <String, Integer>

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, type-conversion

I have a simple Customer class like so

```
public class Customer {
    public int age;
    public int discount;
    public String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Customer(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Customer(String name, int age, int discount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [age=" + age + ", discount=" + discount + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Integer getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }
    public void setDiscount(int discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }
}
```

I populate a list of these objects using this

```
List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Customer("John",   2, 15),
        new Customer("John",   4, 15),
        new Customer("John",   6, 25),
        new Customer("Joe",    3, 15),
        new Customer("Joe",    3, 15),
        new Customer("Joe",    3, 15),
        new Customer("Goerge", 6, 25),
        new Customer("Goerge", 6, 25),
        new Customer("Mary",   7, 25),
        new Customer("Jane",   1, 15),
        new Customer("Jane",   2, 15),
        new Customer("Jane",   8, 25),
        new Customer("Jane",   8, 25)
        ));
```

Now I want to group and count the names and discounts, using a collector like this

```
Map<Object, Long> collected = customerList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> Arrays.asList(x.name, x.discount), Collectors.counting()));
```

I can review my output using this

```
collected.entrySet().forEach(c -> {
    System.out.println(c);
});
```

Which outputs the following

```
[Jane, 15]=2
[Joe, 15]=3
[John, 15]=2
[Mary, 25]=1
[John, 25]=1
[Jane, 25]=2
[Goerge, 25]=2
```

The question is how do I **sort** the Map by name and discount so it looks like this

```
[Goerge, 25]=2
[Jane, 15]=2
[Jane, 25]=2
[Joe, 15]=3
[John, 15]=2
[John, 25]=1
[Mary, 25]=1
```

I keep bumping up against the Object type that is returned by the collector?

Can I cast the collector so that it returns a class, maybe something like

```
private class DiscountCounts
{
    public String name;
    public Integer discount;
}
```

Is it possible to convert the `Map<**Object**, Long>()` to something like `Map<DiscountCounts, Long>()`, would this allow access to the fields of the Map key using lambda or Comparator constructs?

I tried something like this, iterate over the map and manually convert to the Map I want but I can't get to the original collection's keys?

```
    Map<DiscountCounts, Long> collected2 = new HashMap<>();
    collected.entrySet().forEach(o -> {
        DiscountCounts key1 = (DiscountCounts)o.getKey();  //--> Fails here
        collected2.put((DiscountCounts)o.getKey(), o.getValue());
    });
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`?  It sorts its keys automatically.

Comment: Dawood, from the responses below I can see how a TreeMap would've helped here but I would never have understood the Collector object well enough to implement it on my own, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can do it without using `DiscountCounts` class is, first sort the list and then perform the groping by operation, and use `LinkedHashMap` to save the sorted order

```
Map<List<Object>, Long> map = customerList.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getName).thenComparing(Customer::getDiscount))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> Arrays.asList(x.name, x.discount),LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

The another way using `DiscountCounts` class is, by override the `equals` and `hashcode` of `DiscountCounts` class and do a groupingBy creating `DiscountCounts` object for every `Customer` object as key in `Map` and use `TreeMap` with `Comparator` to sort the result

```
Map<DiscountCounts, Long> result = customerList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            c -> new DiscountCounts(c.getName(), c.getDiscount()),
            () -> new TreeMap<DiscountCounts, Long>(
                    Comparator.comparing(DiscountCounts::getName).thenComparing(DiscountCounts::getDiscount)),
            Collectors.counting()));
```

@Andreas suggest in the comment enlighten me another way of doing it, and i feel this is one of the best approach you can implement `Comparable` on  `DiscountCounts` and provide the sorting logic so that you don't need to provide Comparator to `TreeMap`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DiscountCounts cust) {

      int last = this.getName().compareTo(cust.getName());

     return last == 0 ? this.getDiscount().compareTo(cust.getDiscount()) : last;
}

Map<DiscountCounts, Long> result1 = customerList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            c -> new DiscountCounts(c.getName(), c.getDiscount()), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: If using `DiscountCounts`, it would probably be better to make `DiscountCounts` implement `Comparable`, so you don't have to build a `Comparator` for the `TreeMap`.

Comment: Thanks, the second solution worked and gives me the greatest functionality for what I need to do. Full credit for a complete and coherent solution.

Answer (score 0):

With proper `equals` and `hashcode` implementation for `DiscountCounts`, you might be looking for something over the lines of :

```
Map<DiscountCounts, Long> collectSortedEntries = customerList
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> new DiscountCounts(x.name, x.discount),
                Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<DiscountCounts, Long> e) -> e.getKey().getName())
                .thenComparing(e -> e.getKey().getDiscount()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Naman, I like where you;re going with this, your code throws a compiler error on the e -> e.getKey().getName(), but that will be an opportunity for me to learn more about the Comparator.

Comment: @vscoder have updated the answer to fix the compilation, but indeed Andreas comment on the other answer makes sense to update `DiscountCounts` to `implement Comparable<DiscountCounts>` and then further simplify collecting to a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Man, just wanted to tell You that You saved my life with that answer. Have a good life!